# How to raise a new case ( bug or FR ) in JasperReports Server Professional support portal?

Tags: jasperserver

We have a *JasperReports Server* Professional edition. And we have the login credentials for the support portal. But we are unable to find How/Where can we raise the new issue/case in the portal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a paying customer you should raise your cases here [Jasper home support page](http://support.jaspersoft.com/support_my.php)

There's a menu option to 'Cases' where you can click Submit Case

Comment: Ya. But actually we are missing that "Submit Case" option.